# NodeJS express page takes too long to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pageload, page-load-time

I have been working on a project for a while now using NodeJS and express to make a website. It is hosted on heroku right now.

When I was testing it during developement, I did not have any issues with load time. However when I tested it in a different Wifi than usual (which did not differ much in download speed from the usual) some pages suddenly take 40-60 seconds to load as seen below.

[image: waterfall load of page]

[image: waterfall load long]

What I don't understand is the big gap where nothing(?) happens.

I am still studying atm so I am still very inexperienced. Any help is greatly appreciated.
I would also be thankful for any links to best practices on how to go about this as I couldn't really find anything that helped me.

And please let me know if there is any more information needed to diagnose this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "nothing" happening during the big gap. You just missed what is happening. Look at the **top** of the graph. You will see the long green bar that's downloading. That's what's happening. It is downloading the main html file (I think the url is `/`).

It takes 38 seconds (38233 milliseconds) to load the html the first time and 52 seconds (52444 milliseconds) the second time. This is because your html file is 7.5MB - which is around two mp3 files.

The download times are what I would expect from trying to download two mp3 files - around 1 minute.

Find out why your HTML is 7.5MB. That's what is slowing the page load.

Comment: Note: it is your HTML file that is 7.5MB. That just the **text** minus all images, css and javascript is 7.5MB. Your images are a few hundred kB - much smaller than your HTML file.

Comment: Thank you, i found the culprit. I used an inline svg and did not realize that it was that huge since it's loaded into the page during rendering via ejs so it did not show up in the file I was working in. The doc without it is 13KB.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about the “nothing gab”, start by worrying about them images you have: 300k+, 280k+.. and the rest all them pics make your html file to weight 7,45M. So the nothing huge gan is because yow browser is downloading all them pics, plus up on that consider yow free plan at heroku. Them bros are not going to give you their best suite for free

Comment: It's not the pics that are big. You can see in the graph that the pics are quite small. It's the HTML text that is 7.5MB in size. Now, he may have pics or svg or video inside the HTML text that's base64 encoded as data URLs but it's still the HTML text. For HTML to be more than 1MB in size is very weird and he needs to look at what is in the HTML